# Android studio doesn't show my phone while running the application

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying to run my application in my Samsung device.  But Android Studio doesn't show my phone. It doesn't even show the choosing option.

I can access my phone from my computer. USB debugging is also on.

I have tried killing and starting the adb server as i found it online but nothing seems to work.  This is what it shows when I click the run button

[image]

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: doesnt allow me to post the image

Comment: Developers Option is turned on in your phone, right?

Comment: Since you are using Samsung, did you choose the `use as a camera` option after connecting the phone?

Comment: No, I chosed theMedia device

Comment: Also try restarting studio and your computer.

Comment: I hope you have installed a usb driver. If no, please do so

Comment: sorry guys nothing is helping..It was running just fine 2 3 days ago but after i updated my sdk this problem is around

Comment: I had the same problem. For Samsung, driver updation is different. see my question: Cannot update Samsung Galaxy S7 driver to android driver on Windows 7

Answer (score -1):

When you connect the phone to your computer, use the `Connect as camera` option on your Samsung phone. Your Android Studio will be able to now detect your phone.

Go to **Settings** > **USB Computer Conneciton** > Select **`Camera(PTP)`**

Make sure your **Developers Console** is turned on.
Also, **USB Debugging** must be turned on.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? All the answers are downvoted at once?